# 6463-T6 aluminum oxidation and role of water and ethanol vapor

Tags: ph, corrosion

Our issue...in a nutshell:    We use 6463-T6 aluminum as a sampling "cell" for analysis of water and ethanol vapor mixtures in both wet and dry gas variations. As I understand it, the aluminum oxide covering our cells surface is being or has been previously damaged and causing micro-abrasions of its surface. This allows water vapor to "attach" to the cells surface which negatively affects our testing process. Incomplete removal of the water or ethanol vapor within the cell is a failure. We have looked at methods of cleaning the cells to essentially create a newer cleaner oxidized surface. Acid baths, boiling in vinegar, etc.. now we are considering how the metal surfaces pH value can affect the quality or this aluminum oxidation. We are kind of stuck and any assistance on testing protocols or processes to achieve our goal would be appreciated.

Comment: Ethanol slowly reacts with Al to form an ethoxide. Though the cell could be anodized, https://www.wikihow.com/Anodize-Aluminum , to passivate it, the ethoxide reaction might still interfere with critcal measurements.

Comment: Dr Moishe
thanks for the info. will keep it in mind. But it doesnt appear to address my main issue.
this comment system will not allow me to fully comment and explain...not enough characters allowed. I will have to break it into mulitple comments

Comment: thanks for the info. will keep it in mind. But it doesnt appear to address my main issue.
A properly cleaned cell assy will have no issues with ethanol, water vapor, nitrogen gas or ethanol/nitrogen gas mixes. My testing process verifies that the system measures these vapors/gases and also purges out back to or close to the baseline value established at test start. Essentially test no 1 goes like this:

Comment: - system purge to stable baseline value
- stable baseline measurements taken
- filter measurements at baseline taken
- water vapor introduced and stable value measured
- system purge to stable value
- baseline measurements taken
- filter measurements taken
- same process repeats for nitrogen gas.
- calculations occur checking various aspects/ratios etc... of test conducted. looking at relationships between water vapor and baseline, and nitrogen vapor and baseline.

Comment: test no 2 uses a similar process (purging, zeroing, ambient testing, etc...) to introduce a high value ethanol/nitrogen gas mix and then monitor it for a value drop after the gas introduction ceases. Issues are high value drops of the gas mixture that occur within the first 10 and 20 seconds after introduction ceases.

Comment: The system is monitored and tested with a known verified reference cell assembly to ensure no mechanical, electrical or other issues are injected into the test process.

Comment: Our problem is essentially an unknown. We could assume that the aluminum cells oxidation layer has been damaged/changed some way that allows for the vapors to be "trapped" within the cell (pitting??) and thus causing incorrect readings. I have found white residue and white splotches on the cells interior. A cleaning process using boiling vinegar and rinsing seemed to work, but its not a repeatable trusted process. So we are looking at other methods of cleaning.

Comment: We dont have the resources to do a full on metallurgical analysis and full failure analysis....we know the cells are "dirty?" in some way and that cleaning them fixes the issue. We just need to find a good repeatable cleaning method. And we think we should stick with an acidic cleaning approach as acids attack/prefer the oxide layer over the aluminum whereas alkaline cleaning attacks/prefers the aluminum vice the oxide layer.

Comment: It is better to *edit* your question, rather than  add a comment.